# Predicate Logic Statement Requirements

Tags: predicate-logic, word-problem

If I want to translate the following sentences to predicate logic:

> All students enjoy math.

is it ok to specify $x$ are students and just do the following?

$$M(x) = x \text{ enjoys math}$$

so

$$\forall x (M(x))$$

Negation:

∃x (~M(x)) =  There exists a student that does not enjoy math.

Or do I have to use another predicate to specify what x is?

S(x) : x is a student. and then, 
M(x) : x enjoys math.

∀x(S(x)→M(x)) , which should negate to ∃x(S(x) ∧ ~M(x)) .  Similar here, but when statements get more complicated, the negations turn out to be slightly different for the two methods.

Are both acceptable?

Comment: If your entire universe consists of students, the first is fine. But, then who would teach them?

Comment: You should post answers as answers

Comment: @LeeMosher Maybe they could teach each other?

Comment: I thought maybe the first could be okay since the statement does not really consider consider anything but students, but I'm not sure if that's an accepted practice or if it's required to specify what the restrictions(?) on x are in the statement itself.